# What Java/Clojure SPDY clients work for connecting App Engine to Compute Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, clojure, spdy, google-compute-engine

[App Engine recently enabled sockets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/overview), and [Google opened up Compute Engine to everyone](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine) so it's now possible to use SPDY to connect App Engine apps to backend Compute Engine servers.

But there may still be an issue with SPDY library support since popular Java SPDY clients like [Square's okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) use [`java.util.concurrent` classes for its `ConnectionPool`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/ConnectionPool.java#L26) that are not on the [Google JRE whitelist](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist).

Are there SPDY client libraries for Java that Googlers recommend or that are known to work with App Engine?

**UPDATE**: I was mistaken -- the `java.util.concurrent` classes are on the Google JRE whitelist.

I searched for "concurrent" on the whitelist page and found `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`...

```
java.util.Collection
java.util.Collections
java.util.Comparator
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.Currency
java.util.Date
java.util.Deque
```

...and didn't realize there is a whole slew of `java.util.concurrent` classes further down the page.

Thanks to [@jesse-wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40013/jesse-wilson) for pointing that out:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/195

Jesse also said that he had just talked to someone at I/O on the App Engine team about running `OkHttp` on App Engine, and the App Engine person said:

> The larger problem is that OkHttp needs some special SSL classes on
>   the bootclasspath to run on the JVM. You're never going to get that on
>   app engine (too dangerous) so that makes SPDY on App Engine a
>   non-starter for any library.

Furthermore, Jesse said that the SPDY client in `OkHttp` is an internal API that changes so it's not intended to be used as a standalone client.

However, this is SPDY for backend RPC so to deal with the SSL issue on GAE, you should be able to disable SSL and just pass raw SPDY frames to the Compute Engine servers since Compute Engine automatically encrypts communications between servers.

Ilya Grigorik ([@igrigorik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510112/igrigorik)) discusses disabling SSL in his AirBnB TechTalk on SPDY. At the end he makes the case for using SPDY for modern backend RPC instead of stuff like Thrift, etc. See...

"Building a Modern Web Stack"

- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxfEcqJ4MOM
- Slides: http://www.igvita.com/slides/2012/http2-for-fun-and-profit.pdf
- Blog: http://www.igvita.com/2012/01/18/building-a-modern-web-stack-for-the-realtime-web/

So I'm still on the hunt for a Java SPDY client that will work on App Engine. It may mean forking one and stripping out all the SSL stuff, unless one can be made to work by excluding the SSL classes from the build.

Any pointers to good Java SPDY clients is appreciated.

**UPDATE 2**: The guys on the SPDY dev list said Jetty and Netty now have standalone SPDY client libraries:

Jetty SPDY Client:

- http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-spdy
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/SPDY

```clojure
;; Clojure dependencies
[org.eclipse.jetty.spdy/spdy-core "9.0.3.v20130506"]
[org.eclipse.jetty.spdy/spdy-client "9.0.3.v20130506"]
```

Netty SPDY Client:

- http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy.html (codec-http)
- https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/spdy

```clojure
;; Clojure dependency
[io.netty/netty-codec-http "4.0.0.CR3"]
```

There is also Twitter's Finagle SPDY client, which is based on Netty:

Finagle's SPDY Client:

- http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/index.html
- https://github.com/twitter/finagle/tree/master/finagle-spdy

```clojure
;; Clojure dependency
;; [com.twitter/finagle-spdy "6.4.0"]
```

Jetty's SPDY client allows you to run it over SSL or **in the clear** so this may get around App Engine's SSL restrictions, and since Jetty is what App Engine uses for its servlet container, maybe this could be officially blessed or adapted.

I added a feature request to the App Engine issue tracker...

"Add a SPDY Client to the SDK for Connecting to Compute Engine Servers"
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9398

Comment: I think it's important to ask the question "Why do you want to use SPDY?"  The primary gains of the SPDY protocol are in sending multiple assets concurrently, which yields fantastic page load speedups, but if you're hitting an API the gains of SPDY over HTTPS aren't as impressive. What's your goal here?

Comment: Perhaps @igrigorik can elaborate on the gains of SPDY on the backend, but I'm not seeing it personally.  Of course, I defer to his greater knowledge on the topic.